# How do I keep the format of the MATLAB code I'm pasting to word?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to copy and paste code I've written in MATLAB to word, but it automatically reformats the code into black and white and changes the tabbing/spacing.  Is there any way to copy and paste it in the same format?  I'm running MATLAB on a Virtual Machine through my University, so unfortunately I've found that many of the methods suggested on Google are not working.

I figured this question would have already been asked, but it seems most of the copying/pasting questions have to do with graphs.  I haven't seen anything about code format, but if there is a post I missed please point it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless this is a duplicate question, I'm not sure why it has been closed. A quick look will show that only one of the closers has answered more than a few Matlab questions [mitch(4)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:16076+[matlab]), [Michael(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:23897+[matlab]), [Eitan(414)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1336150+[matlab]), Andy(0), NULL(0), suggesting they don't really use Matlab. This falls under "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" domain of SO. This is a pretty regular problem for matlab users.

Comment: Copying and pasting is terribly tedious, unreliable, and error-prone. Have you considered another option? LaTeX's `listings` package, for instance, allows you to insert a listing (MATLAB or other) in your document, with nice syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

m files are plain text files, the syntax highlighting you see is done by the MATLAB editor, and the color coding information is not saved as part of the m file itself. So there's no way to get simple copy-paste to retain syntax highlighting.

As for spacing, you may be able to get satisfactory results by setting the font in your Word file to a monospaced font, instead of a proportional one.

But your best option is to use the [`publish`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) function to export the m file. It will even export to `doc` format directly, or you could export to `html` and then have Word import it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The only issue with publish is that I'm not sure I can actually publish it to my desktop (again because I'm using a virtual machine to run MATLAB).  As far as I can tell, publish will only publish the code to a word file on the virtual machine, which when copied over has the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it will only export the file to your VM, which probably means the VM needs to have Word installed (not sure of this). If that isn't working, try exporting to html, then copying the html file(s) out of the VM and having Word import the html.